# How to join two tables using JOIN

Tags: mysql

Can any please help me how to join two queries in single table

Luminary details table:

```
select 
    mac_id, round(sum(luminary_count::int * wattage::int)::numeric/100, 2) as rated_power 
from 
    luminary_details AS A
join 
    geo_light as gl on A.mac_id = gl.id 
group by
    A.mac_id
```

//lastupdated_all

```
select mac_id, (tactivep::numeric)
from lastupdated_all AS A
join geo_light as gl on A.mac_id = gl.id 
group by A.mac_id
```

Comment: ::int - is not a mysql shortcut?

Comment: so you want to join this two query?

Comment: Are you using Postgres or MySQL?  Perhaps you want a union query here.

Comment: yes.....................................

Comment: ^-- Yes to which question ?

Comment: want to join this two query

Answer (score 0):

You could use geo_ligth as main table and left join the 2 query as subselect  .. joining by id = mac_id

```
select gl.id,  t1.rated_power, t2.tactivep
from  geo_light  gl
LEFT JOIN  (
  select mac_id, round(sum(luminary_count::int * wattage::int)::numeric/100, 2) as rated_power 
  from luminary_details AS A
  join geo_light as gl on A.mac_id = gl.id 
  GROUP BY A.mac_id
)  t1 on t1.mac_id  = gl.id 
LEFT JOIN  (
  select mac_id, (tactivep::numeric) num_tactivep
  from lastupdated_all AS A
  join geo_light as gl on A.mac_id = gl.id 
  GROUP BY A.mac_id
) t2 on t2.mac_id = gl.id
```